# Moving/Grouping Files Unix

Tags: file, unix, directory

I have one folder with about 1000 files and I want to group them according to their resepctive parent folders.

I did `ls- R > updated.txt` to get the original setup of folders and files.

The `updated. txt` looks like this:

```
./Rhodococcus_RHA1:
NC_008268.fna
NC_008269.fna
NC_008270.fna
NC_008271.fna

./Rhodoferax_ferrireducens_T118:
NC_007901.fna
NC_007908.fna

./Rhodopseudomonas_palustris_BisA53:
NC_008435.fna

./Rhodopseudomonas_palustris_BisB18:
NC_007925.fna

./Rhodopseudomonas_palustris_BisB5:
NC_007958.fna

./Rhodopseudomonas_palustris_CGA009:
NC_005296.fna
NC_005297.fna
```

So, by looking at this file, I know what files go into what folder. The folder with all the 1000 files together looks like this:

```
results_NC_004193.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004307.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004310.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004311.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004337.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004342.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004343.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_004344.fna.1.ebwt.map
```

and so on...

You can see that the filenames of all the 1000 files are dependent on their original names in the folder setup(if that's a good way to explain it).

I want to move these `results_XXXXXXXX` files to folders (have to create new folders) with the original setup. So it should be something like this:

```
./Rhodococcus_RHA1: (this is a folder)
results_NC_008268.fna.1.ebwt.map 
results_NC_008269.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_008270.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_008271.fna.1.ebwt.map

./Rhodoferax_ferrireducens_T118:
results_NC_007901.fna.1.ebwt.map
results_NC_007908.fna.1.ebwt.map
```

I don't really know how to do this... maybe some kind of `mov` command? I'd appreciate help with this problem.

Comment: You could do it for sure writing a C or Java program. May be a combination of mv and regulars expressions also could do the trick, but I don't know that kind of tricks to show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command from the folder where you have those 1000 files. The path/to/original/files is the path to the original files (the one that you did ls -R). you should get a list of mv commands. Verify several of them to confirm that those are correct. If so, add | sh next the command and rerun it to execute those commands. If you don't have all the corresponding files in the 1000 files folder, you would get mv commands that would return "file not found", that can be ignored or piped to /dev/null. This assumes that you always have a file in original folder so that it knows where to move the file. If not, some of those 1000 files won't be moved. As always, take a good backup before you do this.

```
find path/to/original/files -type f | awk -F"/" '{ path=$0; sub($NF, "", path); printf("mv results_%s.1.ebwt.map \"%s\"\n", $NF, path);}'
```

Comment: It would generate commands to move the file where the corresponding original file is found. It could be anywhere - in the original folder or a subfolder. This command itself doesn't move. It only generates the mv commands. So you can run it safely as many times as you want. Run it, look at those commands and verify. Only after verification pipe the command's output to sh to actually move the files.

Comment: It does give me a bunch of `mv` commands. When I try to run some of them...it does nothing and gives me a prompt `>` thing. The thing you get when you are writing in script directly into the terminal.

Comment: `mv results_NC_007705.fna.1.ebwt.map ../../../Documents/Winter '12/ECE-S435/Complete_List/Xanthomonas_oryzae_MAFF_311018/
`

Comment: Got it. It needs to be `Winter\ \'12`...wonder how cygwin missed that.

Comment: You have space in the foldername. That is fine but you also got a single quote. Can you post a sample output of find path/to/original/files -type f also? Make sure to include a line that has Xanthomonas_oryzae_MAFF_311018.

Comment: Updated the command to enclose the destination folder in double quotes. That should take care of blank space.

Comment: Nice. This should work cleanly. What If i want to change the path to where it's moving the files? Like I still want the folders and within each the results files, but don't want to change the original ones.

Comment: Pipe the final output to sed  | sed 's|../../../Documents|Whatever/New/Path|'. Make sure that the subfodlers exist in the new path.

Comment: So this should print the move commands to any directory:`find path/to/original/files -type f | awk -F"/" '{ path=$0; sub($NF, "", path); printf("mv results_%s.1.ebwt.map \"%s\"\n", $NF);}| sed 's|../../../Documents|Whatever/New/Path|`

Comment: Yes, change the path between | and |.

Comment: This gives me the same thing that was happening earlier: `find ../../../Documents/Winter\ \'12/ECE-S435/Complete_List/ -type f | awk -F"/" '{ path=$0; sub($NF, "", path); printf("mv results_%s.1.ebwt.map \"%s\"\n", $NF);}'| sed-s| ../../../../../TESTING'/
`

Comment: sed should be forematted properly i.e. sed -s |../ - note - no space after |

Comment: but the way i am piping it makes sense? I removed the `path` from after `$NF` in the `print` statement.

Comment: Oh I did not notice that. You can't do that, at least not without updating the whole printf. Since that part is working fine, I would leave it as is and just work on the sed.

Comment: I will just settle for working with the files in the original folder for now. Will look up `sed` in a while. Thanks for your help